# Javascript new Date returning wrong year

Tags: javascript, date

Using Chrome and and in the console new Date(2015, 12, 20) will
return the following in the Chrome console window...

Wed Jan 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

This also occurs in my javascript (js) file.

I have also tried parseInt with the same result

```
var month = parseInt(valueUnwrapped.getUTCMonth() + 1); //months from 1-12
var day = parseInt(valueUnwrapped.getUTCDate());
var year = parseInt(valueUnwrapped.getUTCFullYear());
var dte = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Comment: What is your system time?

Comment: who is going to find the zero month dupe?

Comment: Drop the ` + 1` from the month line

Comment: @epascarello sometimes it's easier to just answer it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

month value is a 0-based number, 0 being January. If it goes beyond 11, the date rolls over.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: True as it is, this defies expectation or convention. Every other language I've ever encountered uses 1-12 for a numeric month value.

Comment: No argument there. I only knew this off hand because I ran into the same problem a couple months back and thought "well that's stupidly unintuitive"

Comment: Ironically, so did the OP, judging by the first line of the code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

new Date("2015, 12, 20")

Can you try this instead?

Comment: Can you explain your down vote as common courtesy?  Otherwise, it makes no sense whatsoever!

Comment: someone trolling? My answer was downvoted as well without comment.